# Пустой результат при парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь спарсить никнейм человека(на скриншоте). Написал данный код:

```
import requests
import fake_useragent
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

session = requests.session()
user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {"user-agent": user}
personal_page = requests.get(f"https://www.epal.gg/epal/1286057", headers=header).text
personal_page = BeautifulSoup(personal_page, "lxml")
name = personal_page.find("div",class_="text___He8CB epal-single-paragraph epal-name nickname")
print(name)
```

Однако результат кода:

```
<div class="text___He8CB epal-single-paragraph epal-name nickname"></div>
```

Вместо никнейма пустота. Помогите разобраться

Comment: "Помогите разобраться" Сайт динамический.

Answer (score 0):

скорее всего это происходит из-за того, что сайт является динамическим (генерирует страницу сам, а не берет готовую с сервера). Возможно, вам поможет [это видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjq8KSMWxQ4)